# fstab defaults not working as expected

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to mount a partition to `/media/files` so that every user can read, write and execute in it. I first tried:

```
UUID=6c95b3f6-90a5-4092-b30f-7a41210595f4   /media/files    ext4          defaults       0       2
```

which did not solve it.

I now have tried:

```
UUID=6c95b3f6-90a5-4092-b30f-7a41210595f4   /media/files    ext4          exec,rw,user       0       2
```

Without any success either. What should I do? As a sidenote, I want Steam to create a library folder in there.

---

**Update**

I now have also `chmod`-ed the folder `/media/files` to `a+rwx` which allows Steam to create a folder `/media/files/SteamLibrary`. However, it complains that the partition was without execution permissions.

```
iamuser@desktop:/media$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 May 21 19:32 files


iamuser@desktop:/media/files$ ls -l
drwx------ 2 root    root    16384 Mai 21 18:58 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx 3 iamuser iamuser  4096 Mai 21 19:39 SteamLibrary
```

Still using the aforementioned fstab options `exec,rw,user`

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I got this now. What I did with chmod was good, what I did before in fstab was the issue. Now defaults in fstab solves the problem.

So, as a reminder for anybody struggeling:

```
chmod a+rwx /media/files
```

will do the trick!

If anybody as something to add about the rigorous permissions, I am happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

The mount option `user` resets some other options. From [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html):

```
user   Allow an ordinary user to mount the filesystem.  The name of the
       mounting  user  is  written  to  mtab so that he can unmount the
       filesystem again.   This  option  implies  the  options  noexec,
       nosuid,  and  nodev (unless overridden by subsequent options, as
       in the option line user,exec,dev,suid).
…

users  Allow  every  user  to  mount  and unmount the filesystem.  This
       option implies the options noexec,  nosuid,  and  nodev  (unless
       overridden   by  subsequent  options,  as  in  the  option  line
       users,exec,dev,suid).
```

So, you need to specify `exec` *after* `user`:

```
UUID=6c95b3f6-90a5-4092-b30f-7a41210595f4   /media/files    ext4          rw,user,exec       0       2
```

If you want every user to be able to read, write and execute, that's not a job for ext4 mount options, but for permissions, as you have applied them using `chmod`.

As a side note, you might have been better off `chown`ing `/media/files` to your user, instead of giving everybody `rwx`, or using the `user` mount option, and set `rwx` only for you:

```
sudo chown iamuser:iamuser /media/files
sudo chmod a=rX,u+w /media/files
```

That should let Steam (running as your user) create files in the disk.